# How to derive a marginal likelihood function?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I'm a little confused on the integral over ''theta'' of marginal likelihood function (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_likelihood,Section: "Applications"-"Bayesian model comparison", the third equation on this page):

Why does the probability of x given M equal the integral and how to derive the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral is nothing more than than the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_probability) in continuous form.  Thus it can be derived directly from the probability axioms. Given the second formula in the link (Wikipedia), the only thing you have to do to arrive at the formula you are looking for is to replace the sum over discrete states by an integral.

So, what does it mean intuitively? You assume a model for your data X, which depends on a variable theta. For a given theta, the probability of a dataset X is thus p(X|theta). As you are not sure on the exact value of theta, you choose it to follow a distribution p(theta|alpha) specified by a (constant) parameter alpha. Now, the distribution of X is directly determined by alpha (this should be clear ... just ask yourself whether there is something other it might depend on ... and find nothing). Therefore, you can calculate its exact influence by integrating out the variable theta. This is what the law of total probability states.

If you don't get it by this explanation, I suggest you to play a bit around with conditional probabilities for discrete states, which in fact often leads to obvious results. The extension to the continuous case is then straightforward.

---

**EDIT:**  The third equation shows the same which I tried to explain above. You have a model M. This model has parameters theta distributed by p(theta|M) -- you could also write this p_M(theta), for example.

These parameters determine the distribution of the data X via p(X|theta, M) ... i.e. each theta gives a different distribution of X (for a chosen model M). This form, however, is not convenient to work with. What you want is a summarized statement on the model M, not on its various possible choices for theta. So, in a way, you now want to know the average of X given a model M (note that in the model M also a chosen distribution of its parameters is included. For example, M does not simply mean "Neural Network", but rather something like "Neural Network with weights uniformly distributed in [-1,1]").

Obtaining this "average" requires only basic statistics: Just take the model,  p(X|theta, M), multiply it by the density p(theta| M), and integrate over theta. This is essentially what you do for any average in statistics. All together, you arrive at the marginalization p(x|M).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, sir and sorry that I didn't describe the question clearly...  I'm confused on the equation under the section "Applications"-"Bayesian model comparison"(the third equation on that page)...  Apologize for my carelessness once again.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I can understand it now! I also came up with a way: Let's consider the basic sum rule:p(y)=integral of p(y|theta)*p(theta)  now, we just add an additional condition M to each term:p(y|M)=integral of p(y|theta,M)*p(theta|M).   Can it be a correct way of understanding this equation?